# Delete lines based on character(s) in specific position on line

Tags: vim, position, character

I'm working with a large text file and need to be able delete lines based on the value of the 25th character on the line, i.e. if it is equal to H, K or Z. Is this possible, either just by matching one of the letters and running 3 commands or (even better) by all 3 in one command? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [global](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3aglobal) to find a regex and then execute a command on the line that regex was found.

In this case it looks for any character 24 times from the beginning of the line and if the character after it matches `H`, `K`, or `Z` delete that line. (`d` at the end of the command stands for delete).

```
:g/^.\{24\}[HKZ]/d
```

**Edit:** as Peter Ricker points out `\%25c` would also work.

```
:g/\%25c[HKZ]/d
```

`\%25c` matches the 25th column then preforms the regex from there.

You could also use `\%v` if you wanted to match virtual columns instead.

Comment: vimgolf: `:g/\%25c[HKZ]/d`

Comment: @PeterRincker ha! just saw your comment here! :)

Comment: I just upvote your answer, and remove mine. since it is kinda duplicated.

Comment: @Kent Thanks, I also added a line about using `\%v` which was in your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you both - nice solutions which do exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following `ex` command:

```
:if match( "HKZ", strpart( getline("."), 24, 1) ) != -1 | delete | endif
```